# Hide entire table in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a requirement where I need to either show or hide entire table (in cells N47 - S52) based on the value of a cell in P35

Ex : If P35="Yes", show entire table, else hide entire table

I can apply the formula for each cell seperately, but is there a way to do it at once?

Comment: Can you please clarify the last sentence: "I can apply the formula for each cell seperately, but is there a way to do it at once?" Are you saying you have a formula that does this already? Please share what you have already tried so we can help you better.

Comment: Hi, what i meant was, I can use this formula to hide/show a single cell based on a particular cell's value `=IF(P35="Yes","* YES YES YES text", "NO NO NO text")`. I'm looking for a similar functionality to show/hide entire table (N47:S52)

Comment: I'm not sure whether we are understanding each other completely. That's a conditional formula that will show different text based on whether the value `"Yes"` is present in `P35`. That formula alone wouldn't hide/show a single cell, what else are you doing?

Comment: Ravi, try using an absolute reference in your formula. Instead of `P35` use `$P$35`. Then paste the formula wherever you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to go about it, with the below assumptions that:

1. It is okay to move your actual table into a different worksheet and instead leave a reference to the actual table to be shown/hidden
2. The size of the actual table (no of rows and columns) is static. Changes to the size will require changes to your formula in Step#2 on cell B2.

**Step#1:**
Set up a table in a separate worksheet (Sheet2). Check the table name in Design tab (Excel 2016) on the top left corner while one or more cells of your table is selected. in our example below it is Table1 (default).

[image]

**Step#2:**
Next, select the block of cells in Sheet1 where you want your table to "appear"/"disappear" (In this example it is Sheet1 B2:D5) and while you have the selection on, press F2, to enter the below formula in one of the cells. Once done, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter this as an array formula.

`=IF(G2="Yes",Table1[#All],"")`

So when `G2="Yes"`, your table will be visible, any other values and it will disappear!

[image]

Comment: Thankyou, i could get the table dynamically. How to get the table styles aswell - for ex, now just plane text is coming, how to just import the full table with styles

Comment: Ravi, that's a good point that is not covered in this answer. You may want to use the format painter option to copy the format for entire table and paste the format over to the destination cells. Note that this will still not copy the width and height of the cells.